# $e^A=\lim_{j\to +\infty}(I+\frac{1}{j}A)^j$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm wondering if this is true:

> $e^A=\lim_{j\to +\infty}(I+\frac{1}{j}A)^j$

I need help

thanks a lot.

Comment: What's your definition of $e^A$?

Comment: @Raskolnikov $e^A=I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+...$

Comment: $I$ and $A$ commute, so we can expand using the binomial theorem. All the terms then _individually_ tend to the right thing, but the fact that the number of terms is not constant complicates things..

Comment: One more question, in what sense do we have to understand the limit? Is it element-wise? Is it w.r.t. some norm?

Comment: @Raskolnikov no, it's the usual limit.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is true.  $${n \choose k} n^{-k} = \frac{n}{n} \frac{n-1}{n} \ldots \frac{n-k}{n} \frac{1}{k!}$$
(understood to be $0$ when $n < k$), which increases to $1/k!$ as $n \to \infty$.  So, in a matrix norm,
$$\|e^A - (I + A/n)^n\| \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k!} - {n \choose k} n^{-k}\right) \|A\|^k $$
For any $N$, break the sum up into $k \le N$ and $k > N$.  The part for $k \le N$ goes to $0$, while the part for $k > N$ is bounded by $\sum_{k > N} \|A\|^k/k!$ which can be made arbitrarily small by taking $N$ large.

This works, by the way, in any Banach algebra.

EDIT: Since you tagged "differential-equations", I might note that 
you can also interpret this as saying that the $n$-step Euler approximation
to the solution of a homogeneous constant-coefficient linear system converges to the solution
as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Alternatively, note that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{k!}-\binom{n}{k}n^{-k}\right)\Vert A \Vert^k=e^{\Vert A \Vert}-(1+\Vert A \Vert/n)^n$, and use the corresponding result for real numbers.

Comment: Why did this receive a downvote?